# How can I connect a JDBC connection pool for Selenium WebDriver test case?

Tags: jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a Maven application. I'm using JPA and EJB. I need to connect a JDBC connection pool for Selenium-WebDriver test case. Since I want to use a separate database for testing.

How can I specify the Connection pool to use when testing using Selenium-WebDriver? Is there any configuration required? In domain.xml I can configure the attributes for the Connection pool such as "Database name", "port", "user name", "password" etc. But I want to know how can I call this Connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database connection settings separate from selenium-webdriver code. There is no need to couple JPA/EJB connection pools with selenium code. If required create own framework to perform database operations with selenium-webdriver.

Comment: Ok Satish. I can test the application using Selenium without connection pools. But It takes my main database. If I insert a record for testing purpose. It replicates in the database. But we should not have testing values in my main database know. For this case I need to access other database if possible. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: In case of production database i have created a test account for performing user level operations in database. In my case there were some records but you are looking for a complete database. I think you can send some extra request parameters to web-application in case of selenium requests, so that you can recognize the request type and perform on the basis of this.